# JavaScript array forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array named blogs inside the array exists these objects:

```
var blogs = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
image: String,
body: String,
author: {
  id: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "User"
  },
  username: String
 },comments: [
  {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "Comment"
  }
 ],
 created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

i want to make a forEach that only shows the blogs that have the same username example admin.
My forEach code

```
blogs.forEach(function(blog){
// prints blogs
}
```

Comment: `blogs` seems to be a `mongoose.Schema` instance, not an array.

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrays. Make a request to your database, ex. `Blog.find({ user : "admin" })`

Comment: i don't want just to see inside the database which blogs have been made by admin i want to also print the on the webpage